# The URI prefix is not recognized Error While Setting WPF UserControl Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, uri

I am creating a WPF window and loading a user control inside like below:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("Views/ApplicationInfo.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        UserControl versionInfoUserControl = (UserControl)Application.LoadComponent(uri);

        #region Initizalizing the Window, Winodw Proporties and Icon
        Window versionWindow = new Window();


        versionWindow.Height = 250;
        versionWindow.Width = 400;
        versionWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

Now When I am trying to add an application icon like below:

```
 versionWindow.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,component/Images/Ico.png"));
```

I am getting  URI prefix is not recognized error.

*Do I need to change **application** with Application name like:

```
 versionWindow.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://MyApp.MVVM.WPF:,,component/Images/Ico.png"));
```

Even then I am getting the same error

Comment: Just drop the component part from the URI: `@"pack://application:,,,/Images/Ico.png"`.

Comment: Also be aware that the "pack://" prefix is WPF specific.

Comment: Or, if you do use "component" don't forget the semi-colon in front of it "pack://application:,,,;component/path/file.ext".  That being said, the error you actually asked about is just BitmapImage saying it is confused.  As long as you are in a WPF application, the "pack" Uri prefix _is_ defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume I have a project with a folder named Assets and inside a have a png image with build action Resource or Embedded resource.

Then this works:

```
var versionWindow = new Window
                                {
                                    Height = 250,
                                    Width = 400,
                                    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
                                    Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Assets/icon.png"))
                                };

        versionWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
versionWindow.Icon =  BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourProjectName;component/Images/computer.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?