# "The URI prefix is not recognized" in WPF when loading embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm trying to load an XML document in a WPF application, but using a pack URI I keep getting "The URI prefix is not recognized" even though I register the `pack` authority:

```
UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(@"pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Values.xml");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356161/the-uri-prefix-is-not-recognized-error-while-setting-wpf-usercontrol-icon

Comment: Technically, that URI refers to a "Resource", not an "EmbeddedResource". :)  The distinction is subtle and internal. WPF prefers "Resource", WinForms prefers "EmbeddedResource", the RESX Editor creates "EmbeddedResource".